# JQuery & PHP replaceWith

Tags: php, jquery, html, replacewith

I have a php file containing my website's login script. 
If the user doesn't enter the correct password, then the *else* is executed (see code below):

**PHP**

```
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"; 
    echo "$('.error').replaceWith('<h2>Your password is wrong!</h2>')";  
    echo "</script>";
}
```

and I have a blank *h2* for the error to be replaced onsubmit:

```
<div id="error_space">
<h2 class="error"></h2>
</div>
```

The only problem  is that the error **won't** get replaced...

Hope that someone can help!

**EDIT:** I echoed it directly as suggested below.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just echo the error message directly ?

Comment: Wow... talk about not seeing any trees in the forest.  Why manipulate the DOM with JavaScript when you already have total control over the initial construction of the page?

Comment: Agree with both the above

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `'` from your line

```
echo "$('.error').replaceWith('<h2>Your password is wrong!</h2>)";
                                                               ^ here
```

Comment: I was editing the text and forgot to add it back. It **still** doesn't work with it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @WalkOfLife So how does this flow work? Your user POSTs bad data from a form to your `php` script, then based on that, you serve them up a new page where your `else` clause is executed?

Answer (score 3):

u just forgot '

```
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"; 
    echo "$('.error').replaceWith('<h2>Your password is wrong!</h2>')";  
    echo "</script>";
}
```